# Adding DWORD to all registry Sub folders

Tags: c++, registry, directory, subdirectory

Ive been messing around with this code but for the life of me, no matter how much I search I cant find any information about adding a DWORD value to all sub folders that a certain registry folder has.

The line where I specify the folder where all DWORD values get added is this

```
HKEY hKey = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\Tcpip\\Parameters\\Interfaces\\");
```

It adds them to Interface folder, but instead of that I want to add the DWORD values to all existing subfolders that the Interface folder in registry has. Ive tried a couple of things but it totally messed it up.

Does it anyone have any tips? I guess Im using the wrong terminilogy when searching for an answer to this problem.

Thanks in advance fellas!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the parent key with [`RegOpenKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`RegOpenKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. Enumerate all of the child keys of the parent using [`RegEnumKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`RegEnumKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a loop
3. For each child key, set the desired value with [`RegSetValueEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
4. Close the parent key with [`RegCloseKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried messing with those but I couldnt get any good understanding of how to do it properly and I spent hours on having errors and failing. It almost turned into a 3 hour comedy run, haha.

I made another question with more details so that maybe someone could help by showing it in the code.

Thanks for your help aswell mate! I really got a better understanding of how things work, even though I couldnt implement that thing into my code. : )